# Restaurants in Leipzig, Germany that offer local food

Tags: germany, restaurants, local-cuisine, leipzig

Personally I'm interested in food and cooking. I'm planning a visit to Leipzig, Germany this summer and I wanted to try some of the local dishes of Germany.

What are the most significant dishes in Germany's local cuisine?

Comment: Remove your second question since it would make it non-constructive.

Comment: Walk down the street. > Find the eateries that many locals are queuing to enter. > Ensure signage is more German than English. > Optional - language may prevent, probably not: Ask people in queue what the attraction is. || Just using the 1st 2 steps works in Asia :-) [Change language in instructions to suit :-) ].

Comment: @RussellMcMahon that's clever :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have enough personal experience to recommend specific restaurants but two dishes associated with Leipzig are [Leipziger Allerlei](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leipziger_Allerlei) (well-known everywhere in Germany) and the [Leipziger Lerche](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leipziger_Lerche).

Also worth a try if you see it on a menu is “Soljanka”. This is a soup of (I believe) Russian origin that was popular in the German Democratic Republic and is still served across the East of Germany.

Comment: [Солянка](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0) as you have mentioned is a Russian soup made of various meats with spices.  I'd pass on it since it generally doesn't have a set recipe and isn't a traditional German dish anyway

Comment: I would argue with that, both the set recipe part and the traditional part. What's traditional German? Known in the whole of Germany? Known in the 19th Century? This is all pretty artificial, if you order Soljanka in East Germany, you know what you will get and you are certainly eating something that became part of the local culture.